# Angular reactive form Input view with different value

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have complicated form with FormArray with many different FormGroups. Inside one type of formGroup I have control with value of percent. I need show and edit it value as numbers in 1 - 100, and save all form with quota value 0.1 - 1 (post to server).
I can do some change in store function, but I have to check all items in FormArray if it is formGroup that I need to change. Also I need to update it when I get value to patchValue to form.
Can I differ view and value in control in reactive form?

Comment: Do you want to present your control's value like `numbers` 1-100 and want to store as `percentage` in `db`? Do you only have 1 field of this kind? And also please include your `formArray` code

Comment: I thought you can’t mix reactive form and ngModel. So thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

simple way, using [ngModel] and  (ngModelChange)

```
<input [ngModel]="form.get('percent').value" 
   (ngModelChange)="this.form.get('percent').setValue((+$event)/100)
   [ngModelOptions]="{standalone:true}">
```

Well, this is for a fomControl, but as you has a formArray, I supouse you need has a function that return the formControl

```
getControl(index:number)
{
     return (this.form.get('nameOfArray') as FormArray)
               .at(index)
               .get('percent')
}
```

and use `[ngModel]="getControl(i).value"` and `(ngModelChange)="getControl(i).setValue((+$event)/100)`

remember that the formControl and formArray exist even there are not a input

Comment: Thank you! I get what I want - the way I can use in other formGroups. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-reactive-forms-rbglar